# Check and Validate Java Array using while loop

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, contains, joptionpane

I need some help with a code.
I need to;

- **Make a program that asks for topics you will be talking about, and then talk about them.**
- **the program should check arrays for '?' and say questions not allowed**
- **and check for topics they entered and ask them to "tell more about
  'x' "**
- **end if cancel is pressed in Joption or if it contains 'bye'**

Here is my code so far;

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ATSEStage2 {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    String tmma = "Tell me more about ";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi, Welcome to ATSE \nStarting Input taking Phase...");



    int N = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many Topics will you be talking about?"));
    double [] topics;
    topics = new double [N];
    String [] kw = new String[N];
    String [] chat = new String [N];

    int i=0; int a=1;
    while(i<N) {
    kw [i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Topic "+a);
    System.out.println(kw [i]);
    i++;
    a++;
    }
    i=0;a=0;

    String formattedString = Arrays.toString(kw)
            .replace("[", "")  
            .replace("]", ""); 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "The Topics you entered were, " +formattedString + "\nStarting Chatting phase...");

    int e=0;
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(kw);


        chat [e] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, tmma + formattedString);

        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(chat);
        while(e==0) {

            If (list1.contains("?"));{chat [e] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, tmma + formattedString);
        e++;
        }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!.

Comment: What is the problem that you are having with this code? Do you have an error message? Not the right output?

Comment: The problem is, not being able to check/ Validate the words in the array and loop it if it contains a specific word

Comment: I see that you have a capitalized `if`. In Java `if`'s are lower case.

Comment: Also you have a semicolon after the `if` statement. Remove that

Comment: What is `topics` meant to be for?

Comment: Same question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796328/rebuilding-java-program-with-arrays-and-while-loops-removing-the-do-whiles/51798253#51798253). Why?

Answer (score 0):

@Lonath Senevirathne, you are using the `contains()` method of the `List` class. If you open it you will see it's description says `Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).`. If you want to be able to check/ Validate the words in the array and loop it if it contains a specific word you should iterate through all list elements

```
while (e == 0) {

    for (String st : list1) {
        if (st != null && st.contains("?")) {
            chat[e] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, tmma + formattedString);
            e++;
        }
    }
}
```

With the `while loop`

```
int idx = 0;
while(idx < list1.size()) {
   if (list1.get(idx) != null && list1.get(idx).contains("?")) {
        chat[e] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, tmma + formattedString);
        e++;
   }
   idx++;
}
```

Also you have the infinite `while loop` if `list1` does not contains `?`